# .tif to .png conversion in Android

Tags: android, png, tiff

As android doesn't support TIIF fromat, so I want to convert a .tif image to .png image in android.

Is there any library or code that can help me out?

whatever i get is not saufficient for this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

i would try http://www.schaik.com/png/tiff2png.html and convert his .c file to .rs so that it works on all android platforms. Or better yet just do the conversion before it gets to the phone.